# Array with rand() works locally but not on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

The following works locally:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/rand' do
  ["one", "two", "three"][rand(0..2)]
end
```

However, on heroku, I get a `Internal Server Error`.

Interestingly, this works:

```
get '/rand' do
  ["one", "two", "three"][rand(2) - 1]
end
```

Why?

Comment: and what's in your heroku logs when you get the internal server error? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval

Comment: Let try [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is the method rand only started accepting range values after (I believe) 1.9.3 . Heroku uses Ruby 1.9.1. You can verify this by looking at the heroku logs. You just have to devise a way to use integer value instead of range value.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're using the same version of ruby on heroku and you local dev machine:

Run `ruby -v` locally and on heroku: `heroku run 'ruby -v'`

Then, set the version of ruby heroku uses by adding `ruby "1.9.3"` to your Gemfile.